# Partial order Proof

Tags: order-theory

> Suppose that $<$ is a partial order on a set $A$. Prove that there exists a linear order $<'$ on $A$ such that for all $x,y \in A$, if $x < y$ then $x <' y$.

Please someone give me a simple proof.

Comment: it sounds like a Zorn's lemma proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Morally, what you want to do is just add strong inequalities between elements that are not distinguishable by $<$, and leave everything else as it is.

Formally, things might get a little less pleasant, and some application of the axiom of choice cannot be avoided, I think. You could use Kuratowski-Zorn lemma to mimic an inductive construction. Let $Ord$ be the family of partial orders $<'$ on $A$ that for any $x,y$, if $x < y$ then $x <' y$ (but it might happen that the partial order $<$ does not distinguish $x$ and $y$, i.e. $x \not < y$ and $y \not < x$ --- but $x <' y$). Now, establish order on $Ord$ (yes, it is order on a set orders...) by declaring $<''$ to be larger than $<'$ iff for any $x,y$, from $x <' y$ it follows that $x <'' y$. If you think of orders as sets of pairs, this is just the inclusion order. You can check that the assumptions of Kuratowski-Zorn lemma are satisfied (i.e. each chain has an upper bound), so by the lemma, there exists a largest element, say $<_{max}$. I claim that this maximal element is in fact a total order. For suppose it is not. Then, there are $x$ and $y$ such that $x \not <_{max} y$ and $y \not <_{max} x$. Define an order $<'$ by defining $u <' v$ if and only if either $u <_{max} v$ or $u = x$ and $v = y$. **Edit**: This is *not yet* a partial order, but it *can be extended to a partial order*, which is larger that $<_{max}$ --- a contradiction. So, $<_{max}$ is really a total order, so we are done.

---

Many thanks to Julien for pointing out the gap in the original post. See other answers for more details

Comment: Thanks for all of you, especially Feanor !!

Comment: @julien Thanks dear for your replies. I only need total (linear) order. At least I have got the idea.

Comment: Your relation $<'$ is not transitive unless you pay a special attention to that. It can't be that easy.

Comment: @julien: Ah, yes, of course you are correct! But if we add the relations implied by transitivity, things should work, right? I only intended this as a sketch, and apparently things are not as easy as it seemed at first. For the sake of completeness, I'll edit to include this, soon (although your solution seems rather complete).

Comment: Actually, this has to do with the transitive closure of a relation. I don't think we can make it much easier thatn what I wrote. But I'm far from being an expert in the field...

Comment: I don't think it can be made easier too. I didn't see much point in re-writing what you have already written, so I just added the note that there is something missing.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** the result you want is known as the [order-extension principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-extension_principle#Order-extension_principle). The crux of the argument is to show that a maximal extension of the initial order is a total order. The verifications leading to the application of Zorn are routine.

The set of partial orders on $A$ is partially ordered by: $<$ is not greater than $<'$ if $x<y\Rightarrow x<'y$.

The set of partial orders on $A$ which extend (i.e. are not lower than) $<$ is non-empty, of course. If $(<_i)_i$ is a chain of such partial orders, then define
$$
x<'y\qquad\mbox{if}\qquad \exists i\;\;x<_iy.
$$
This is an upper bound for the chain, and again an extension of the initial $<$.

By Zorn, there is a maximal such partial order $<_m$. We will show that it is total.

Assume for a contradiction that $x_0\not<_m y_0$ and $y_0\not<_mx_0$. We define a binary relation on $A$ as follows:
$$
x R y\qquad\mbox{if}\qquad x<_my\quad\mbox{or}\quad\{x<_mx_0\;\mbox{and}\;y_0<_my\}.
$$
It is clearly reflexive. It is also transitive. There are four cases to consider, given $x Ry$ and $yRz$. The last one is not possible by $y_0\not<_mx_0$. By definition, $xRy$ whenever $x<_my$, and $x_0Ry_0$. If $R$ was an order relation (i.e. antisymmetric, which is the only thing we haven't checked), it would be a strict extension of $<_m$, contradicting the maximality of the latter. Therefore, $R$ is not antisymmetric, so there exist $a\neq b$ such that $aRb$ and $bRa$. Again, given the definition of $R$, there are four cases to consider:

1) $a<_mb$ and $b<_ma$: this implies $a=b$ by antisymmetry of $<_m$, impossible.

2) $a<_mb$ and $b<_mx_0$ and $y_0<_ma$: then $y_0<_ma<_mb<_mx_0$ hence $y_0<_mx_0$, impossible.

3) $a<_mx_0$ and $y_0<_mb$ and $b<_ma$: then $y_0<_mb<_ma<_mx_0$ hence $y_0<_mx_0$, impossible.

4) $a<_mx_0$ and $y_0<_mb$ and $b<_mx_0$ and $y_0<_ma$: then $y_0<_ma<_mx_0$ so $y_0<_mx_0$, impossible.

We have reached the desired contradiction, so $<_m$ is a total order on $A$ extending $<$.

Comment: @Zirko Tammado I have written a detailed proof that a maximal order extending $<$ is total. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply Zorn's Lemma to the partially ordered set of all partial orders on $A$, ordered by declaring $\mathord{\prec}$ to be less than $\mathord{\prec^\prime}$ iff $x \prec y$ implies $x \prec^\prime y$ for all $x , y \in A$.  (You will have to show that maximal elements of this partial order are linear orders on $A$.)

Comment: @julien Are you with me ?? or ?

Comment: @ZirkoTammado What do you mean?

Comment: @julien 'I've got the same argument, but like you, I did not prove that a maximal order is total. I see now that the order-extension principle is considered as an axiom. I confess I'm not sure how to prove it. Do you have a reference?' I mean this talk, "you asked me for reference"

Comment: @ZirkoTammado My comment was intended for Arthur Fisher.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I finally came up with a proof that maximal implies total. If you know a more elegant way, I'll be happy to see that.